# How do I use model's define to filter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In django 1.8  python3.4

view.py

```
Bid_data = Bid.objects.filter(uncomplete()=True)
```

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

model.py

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    time_start = models.DateTimeField()
    time_end = models.DateTimeField()
    bid_text = models.CharField( max_length=200, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bid_text

    @property
    def uncomplete(self):
        if datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s') > self.time_end.strftime('%s'):
            return False
        return True
```

How do I use model's define to filter?

Comment: Why would you convert the dates to strings before comparing?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you don't. You can only work on fields in the database

```
Bid.objects.filter(time_end__gt=datetime.now())
```

As an aside, theres a good reason you don't want to. Currently when you call your `uncomplete` method, you need to make a database query just to retrieve the `time_end`. So using this inside of the filter would require you to make two queries instead of just the one

Answer (score 1):

You can filter only by model fields.

As a solution I can suggest adding a [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/) with that method:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class BidManager(models.Manager):

    def uncomplete(self):
        return self.filter(time_end__gt=timezone.now())


class Bid(models.Model):
    time_start = models.DateTimeField()
    time_end = models.DateTimeField()
    bid_text = models.CharField( max_length=200, default="")

    objects = BidManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bid_text

# and then you can do
query = Bid.objects.uncomplete()
```